# WPF XAML - Line not showing up at all

Tags: wpf, xaml

I made a simple UI where I wanted to make a border to a `Grid` row's bottom. I aimed a using a `Line` like so:

```
<Window x:Class="HP_hf_shop.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HP_hf_shop"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="800"
    >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin="10,0,10,0">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.05"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.15"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.85"/>
                <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.95"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,30,10,10">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </Button>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </Button>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,30,10,10">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

I tried using a solid colour onstead of the Brush I set up here and I made sure that when I highlight the line itself, the highlight does have a coverage (it appears as a rectangle opposed to a single line, so it should be visible).
Be advised I'm not using a `Canvas`. The line is on the `Grid` with some buttons. Any ideas why the line doesn't show up at all, not even during runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any ideas why the line doesn't show up at all, not even during runtime?

You need to set the `X1` and `X2` properties of the `Line` for a horizontal line to be drawn:

```
<Line Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" StrokeThickness="10" Margin="10,0,10,0"
          X1="0" X2="100">
    <Line.Stroke>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.05"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.15"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.85"/>
            <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.95"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Line.Stroke>
</Line>
```

If you want the brush to fill the grid row you should probably use another element that stretches to fill the available space, like for example a `Border`:

```
<Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Margin="10,0,10,0">
    <Border.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.05"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.15"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.85"/>
            <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.95"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.Background>
    <TextBlock />
</Border>
```

Comment: It really worked. Now, how to add the X2 to be at the end of the line (as it is set to stretch)?

Comment: I copy pasted the code and it runs but doens't appear either :/

Comment: So the Line did show up but not the Border? Please post your full XAML markup including the Grid.

Comment: Yes, your solution for the line did, the border not at all. Code updated

Comment: Any luck yet? I tried messing around on my end but to no avail

Comment: Put something inside the Border, like for example an empty TextBlock.

Comment: Or set its Height. Simpler than a Border would be a Rectangle with a fixed Height.

Comment: The textbox solution partally worked, it gets _outlined_ with a grey colour, but the gradient brush doesn't show up. I wrote `<TextBox/>` inside it btw.
Trying the rectangle now...

Comment: Did you try setting the Height of the Border to like 20 or 50?

Comment: I tried the height but didn't help either :/. But the rectangle did its job, `Clemens` you might want to convert that to an answer, and `mm8` I upvote yours too. Thank you both for your helps!

Comment: You should also change the Height of the first RowDefinition from 2* to Auto if you set the Height of the Border.

Comment: That way it works. But then it's misplaced :/ Rectangles solved it, though I'm not sure if I can place something else inside when I already have a rectangle. In that case I might want to define another row just for this line.

EDIT: well no, the textbox I planed inside doesn't bother the rect.